# Pandas loc not filtering properly

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I am using pandas to read a csv file and then trying to filter by some condition to remove blank/null/NaN values and then sorting. it still does not filter and returns all the contents. Below is the code. The cells in the csv under the"Status" columns either have some value or they are blank and in some cases have the actual word "NaN."

```
df = pd.read_csv("**************", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df = df.loc[(df["Status"] != "Ready") | (df["Status"] != "NaN") | (df["Status"] != "") | (df["Status"] != " ")]
df = df.sort_values(by=["Room Number"])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: replace "NaN" with np.NaN and import numpy as np

Answer (score 0):

if u want to remove rows with na, u can use code pd.dropna(axis = 0).
for changing " " and any cell for nan befor removing nan, u can use below:
df.replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)

Comment: if you want to remove rows with `na`, you can use code `pd.dropna(axis = 0)`.
for changing " " and any cell for `nan` before removing `nan`, you can use below:

    df.replace(' ', np.nan, inplace=True)